# How to remove 0 from the second column in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I ahve a script which fetches user name and mobile from a file in following format

```
**Current Format**
username        mobile
zzz             03333012345
123             03212334343
245             3712323689
```

Now I want that if the mobile number starts from '0' then only '0' should be removed, so all mobile numbers should be displayed like

```
**Required format:**
username        mobile
zzz             3333012345
123             3212334343
245             371232368
```

(& if the mobile doesn't have zero in start, leave it as it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following  awk for this to ensure only the leading 0s from the second column are removed

```
    awk '{gsub("^0","",$2); print $1,$2}' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Just `sub`, since you want to replace a single instance of `0`. However this also removes all the occurences of the field separator (` `) after the first field.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this code snippet:

> sed 's/\ [0]//g' test.1

Note that, there is space before [

e.g.

```
root@SHW:/tmp # cat test.1 
**Current Format**
username        mobile
zzz             03333012345
123             03212334343
245             3712323689
root@SHW:/tmp # sed 's/\ [0]//g' test.1 
**Current Format**
username        mobile
zzz            3333012345
123            3212334343
245             3712323689
```

It works for me on ubuntu-14.04

Comment: above command is not chanign any thing in the file. I only want that if mobile number (which is in second column) starts from 0, then the 0 should remove.

Comment: This eats the leading ` ` in case of a match, you should place a space into your substitution string; also you don't need to match 0 as a character class containing 0, just match 0; finally the `g` modifier is unuseful since you need to match just a single instance: `sed 's/\ 0/ /' test.1`

Comment: You want `sed 's/\([[:blank:]]\+\)0\+/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -pe 's/ 0([0-9]+)$/ $1/' > outputfile
```

- `-p`: places a `while (<>) {[...]}` loop around the script and prints the processed lines
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `0([0-9]+)$`: matches and groups one or more digits at the end of the line preceeded by a 0 digit preceeded by a  character
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `$1`: replaces with a space followed by the captured group
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers

Answer (score 0):

And in `bash` you can use:

```
while read username mobile
do
    echo "${username} ${mobile/0/}"
done < inputfile
```